# How to move particular window to center in Python?

Tags: python, window, center, python-3.8

I want to move particular window to center in Python.

I’m not talking about my window made with tkinter. I want center other running window in PC.

For example, I am running LeagueClient.exe(League of Legend client), And with some functions, I want to move the LeagueClient.exe window to center.

Is there any library or way to do this?

I’m using Windows 10 and Python 3.8. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow) is something.

Comment: This is great, but how can I use this in Python?

Comment: using the [win32api bindings](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) for python.